# Dynamic Linq Property Converting to Sql

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, properties, expression

I am trying to understand dynamic linq and expression trees.  Very basically trying to do an equals supplying the column and value as strings.  Here is what I have so far

```
 private IQueryable<tblTest> filterTest(string column, string value)
    {
        TestDataContext db = new TestDataContext();

        // The IQueryable data to query.
        IQueryable<tblTest> queryableData = db.tblTests.AsQueryable();

        // Compose the expression tree that represents the parameter to the predicate.
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(tblTest), "item");


        Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, column);
        Expression right = Expression.Constant(value);
        Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);

        MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { queryableData.ElementType },
            queryableData.Expression,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<tblTest, bool>>(e1, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }));

        // Create an executable query from the expression tree.
        IQueryable<tblTest> results = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<tblTest>(whereCallExpression);

        return results;
    }
```

That works fine for columns in the DB.  But fails for properties in my code eg

```
public partial class tblTest
{
    public string name_test
    {  get { return name; }  }
}
```

Giving an error cannot be that it cannot be converted into SQL.  I have tried rewriting the property as a Expression<Func  but with no luck, how can I convert simple properties so they can be used with linq in this dynamic way?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use non-table properties, you'll need to first materialize the query and use LINQ to objects.   I don't think you can query against both SQL and non-SQL properties at the same time for the reason that you state: non-SQL properties have no SQL translation.  I suspect that if you do a `ToList()` before calling `filterTest()`, you'll find that your code works just fine for both types of properties.  Unfortunately, this probably isn't what you want and, if your non-SQL property is derived from various SQL columns, you will need a way to generate an expression that matches the property definition instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping it would be possible to convert simple tasks from an Expression into SQL (Things that should be possible in sql eg joining columns etc) would mean sorting and filtering could be handled in the db.  I appreciate complex scenarios are not possible in the db but was hoping basic properties could be converted or constructed in such a way that they can be handled in the db.

Comment: @Matthew - You might want to look at using PredicateBuilder to build complex filters -- this is what I use: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx